# Shell script: variables inside curl body

Tags: shell

I need to interpolate curl body with variables into a shell script:

This is the script snippet:

```
    curl -k \
      -X PUT \
      -d @- \
      -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
      -H "Accept: application/json" \
      -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
      "$SERVER_URL/api/v1/namespaces/$NAMESPACE/secrets/$SECRET_ID" <<-'EOF'
      {
        "kind": "Secret",
        "apiVersion": "v1",
        "metadata": {
          "name": "$SECRET_ID"
        },
        "stringData": {
          "$key": "$value"
        }
      }
EOF
```

However, neither `$SECRET_ID` nor `$key` nor `$value` aure "resolved".

**EDIT**

I've tried that:

```
    curl -k \
      -X PUT \
      -d @- \
      -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
      -H "Accept: application/json" \
      -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
      "$SERVER_URL/api/v1/namespaces/$NAMESPACE/secrets/$SECRET_ID" <<-"EOF"
      {
        "kind": "Secret",
        "apiVersion": "v1",
        "metadata": {
          "name": "$SECRET_ID"
        },
        "stringData": {
          "$key": "$value"
        }
      }
EOF
```

But it doesn't works.

Answer (score 2):

You quoted your JSON in heredoc with `<<-'EOF'`. If the heredoc delimiter is quoted, it will not expand variables. Use `<<-EOF` to get the normal double-quoted variable-expansiony semantics.

Comment: the double-quoted delimiter still inhibits variable expansion.